# Archive Eventlog every x days

Tags: group-policy, windows-event-log, eventviewer, wevtutil

I have a large number of 2k12 r2 servers and I'd like to keep archives of their Eventlogs every 30 days.
I was looking for a centralized solution, possibly a GPO.
But from what I saw it's only possible to use Group Policy in order to either archive the logs by filesize or retain them for a certain amount of time.
Is there a way to combine between the two to get what I want or am I best to simply script it using wevtutil?

Comment: You should [answer your own question](https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer) with that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the following ABSOLUTELY INCREDIBLE Powershell script: http://mctexpert.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/backup-event-logs-on-multiple-servers.html It does everything I wanted and then some.